# Location of Gacutil with vs 2008

Tags: gacutil

I want to run a post build script that installs the dll in the gac, but i have to use the full path to gacutil.exe, where can i find this? i have visual studio 2008

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\gacutil.exe

Comment: If you're looking for this out on a Server, you'll need to install the SDK. Links can be found here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2006/02/08/527663.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Open the Visual Studio command prompt (Start -> Programs -> Visual Studio -> Visual Studio Tools -> Visual Studio Command Prompt). Run the following command:

```
c:\Program Files...\> where gacutil
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy gacutil to server from your dev PC:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\
  gacutil.exe
  gacutil.exe.config
  1033\gacutlrc.dll
```