# Where is Gacutil.exe?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, global-assembly-cache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Location of Gacutil with vs 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885261/location-of-gacutil-with-vs-2008)

I can't seem to find an answer to where Gacutil.exe is located?   I'm on Windows 7, have all of the current .NET versions from 1.0 to 4.0, and visual studio 2008 and 2010 Professional installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Dupes : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397479/where-is-gacutil-exe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055880/where-does-vs-2010-tools-gacutil-exe-install-assemblies http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373956/two-locations-of-gacutil-exe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885261/location-of-gacutil-with-vs-2008

Comment: Also see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660355/net-4-0-has-a-new-gac-why

Answer (score 2):

i'm runing a windows 7(x64) with vs2008 and my gacutil is in : "c:\program files\Microsoft SDKs\windows\v6.0A\Bin"